# Trouble with libv8 3.16.14.3 on OS X Mavericks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

The Rails project I'm working on includes the gem 'therubyracer' on its Gemfile. When I do 
`bundle install` I get the following error:

```
...
Using launchy 2.4.2
Using less 2.4.0
Using less-rails 2.4.2

Bundler::GemspecError: Could not read gem at /Users/Swanros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@c-bullz/cache/libv8-3.16.14.3-x86_64-darwin-12.gem. It may be corrupted.
An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.16.14.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

When I do `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3` it succeeds, and I cant finish bundling my project.

I've already uninstalled libv8, reinstalled it again, as well as therubyracer, and I still can't manage to get this to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:

`rm -rf /Users/Swanros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@c-bullz/cache/`

:D

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem when I upgraded from OSX Mountain Lion to OSX Mavericks.

Upgrading from ruby-1.8.7-p354 to ruby-1.8.7-375 did the trick for me.

assuming you use rbenv:

```
rbenv install 1.8.7-p375
rbenv rehash
rbenv global 1.8.7-p375
bundle install
```